# JDK 11 on Alpine x86

Tags: java, alpine-linux

There doesn't seem to any JDK 11 build on the Alpine x86 repositories. Are there pre-made binaries from another repository?

Comment: Are you sure you need 32-bit? Most things are 64-bit these days.

Comment: My system only supports x86, unfortunately.

Comment: You can currently download an x86 (32 bit) Java 11 JDK from the Azul "Zulu Community Downloads" site: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?architecture=x86-32-bit&package=jdk

Comment: (For Linux.  It is available in "tar.gz", "zip", "rpm" and "deb" formats.  Or for Windows.)

Comment: @StephenC Is it Alpine compatible?  They use another libc to my understanding.

Comment: @MarwanAmireh If your system only supports x86, you should probably choose the distribution you use based on what software is available for it, and not the other way around.

Comment: Good question.  I don't know.  (And good advice!!)

Comment: Alternative advice ... invest in some new hardware so that you can run a 64 bit OS and JDK.   But the point is that if you insist on running old hardware / operating systems, you are limiting your options for running the latest software.  (Not that Java 11 is "latest".)

Comment: Just for the record, the Raspberry 4 is cheap, quite potent, runs Linux and has Java 11 available.  That is probably the cheapest way to get supported hardware.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I may be wrong, but it looks like running a JDK on x86 Alpine Linux is not a thing, as I've been told that a JDK requires glibc, and there isn't x86 glibc on the Alpine repos or anywhere else.